# PowerBuilder Insert Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

I have a huge problem with a PowerBuilder coded application. It's occuring in all DataWindows. When the control builds it's SQL Syntax for UPDATE/INSERT it's missing the "'" around the datetime fields. That generates a SQL Syntax error.

Example

```
INSERT .... date=12/12/2001 00:00:00 ..
```

CORRECT

```
INSERT.... date='12/12/2001 00:00:00'
```

What can i do?

Comment: What changed? New database?, driver?, Powerbuilder version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

1. Check in your database profile setup if you have a wrong datetime format (Tools\Database Profile), Tab 'Syntax'
2. What kind of DB are you using ? (SQLServer, Oracle, ...) ? If you are using SNC Native , try to change the provide to another option and try again.

Regards.